# Incorrect example in editing-help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

Both https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex and https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex have incorrect mathjax syntax in the example given. It is

```
The *Gamma function* satisfying $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\quad\forall
n\in\mathbb N$ is via through the Euler integral
```

but should have been

```
The *Gamma function* satisfying \$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!\quad\forall
n\in\mathbb N\$ is via through the Euler integral
```

Can this be fixed?

Update: added pictures showing the result.

---

[image: example 1]

---

[image: example 2]

---

Comment: Any reference to why the example is incorrect? It seems to render just fine.

Comment: @m0sa The escapement for the Mathjax syntax on EE.SE is `\$` instead of just `$`.

Answer (score 1):

The editing help now takes into account the delimiter on each site rather than a hard coded `$`, enjoy!

Comment: Excellent, although the accompanying text also needs an update; it currently says `You can use single dollar signs to delimit inline equations`, but it should state `You can use backslash dollar ...`.